# Inserting the following statement in Sqlite C++

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I am currently using an SQlite client and it adds items into a table using the following query

```
INSERT INTO "main"."MyTable" ("urn","total") VALUES (?1,?2)
Parameters:
param 1 (text): sdsdds
param 2 (integer): 23
```

Now I am translating that to c++ as such

```
const char *sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO main.MyTable VALUES(`abc`, 12);";
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlInsert, NULL, NULL, &error);
   if (rc)
   {
      cerr << "Error executing SQLite3 statement: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl << endl;
      sqlite3_free(error);
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Inserted a value into MyTable." << endl << endl;
   }
```

However it seems that the sqlite statement for inserting is invalid. Any suggestions  on what I might be doing wrong ? An example translating the above to a prepared statement would be appreciated

Comment: notice that in your first code the SQL has the field names ("urn" ,"total") and your second code it does not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `''` single quotes for quoting string literals. (Use `` ` ` `` backticks for quoting identifiers such as table and column names.)

If you want to use `?` placeholders for literals, you can. Replace `sqlite3_exec()` with `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` followed by `sqlite3_bind_...()` and `sqlite3_step()`.

Comment: Could you give a simple example please

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your query string in the following way:

```
const char *sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO \"main\".\"MyTable\" (\"urn\",\"total\") VALUES('abc', 12);";
```

It contains fields list as in your initial query, preserves quotation and fixes quotes for constant string.

Answer (score 0):

You need different quotation marks.

```
sqlite> create temporary table foo (urn TEXT, total INTEGER);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES(`abc`, 12);
Error: no such column: abc
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES('abc', 12);
```

Also, with C++ you'd better use a more convenient API. SQLite has [tons](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers) of these. (I would've used [my own](http://code.google.com/p/libglim/)).